# Customizing OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider in Spring Security SAML2

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-saml2

I need to use a legacy `UserDetailsService` with Spring Security SAML2, so I'm following [these instructions from Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.6.0/servlet/saml2/login/authentication.html#servlet-saml2login-opensamlauthenticationprovider-userdetailsservice). However, I get an error when I just try to replace the `AuthenticationProvider` with the supposedly "default" one according to that documentation:

```java
public class WigWebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider();
    // I've tried removing these 2 lines and I get the same error
    authenticationProvider.setAssertionValidator(OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider.createDefaultAssertionValidator());
    authenticationProvider.setResponseAuthenticationConverter(OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider.createDefaultResponseAuthenticationConverter());

    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests(authz -> authz.anyRequest().authenticated())
      .saml2Login(saml2 -> saml2.authenticationManager(new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider)));
  }
}
```

When I do this, I get the following error when I try to authenticate:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.opensaml.saml.saml2.assertion.SAML20AssertionValidator.<init>(Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/util/Collection;Lorg/opensaml/saml/saml2/assertion/AssertionValidator;Lorg/opensaml/xmlsec/signature/support/SignatureTrustEngine;Lorg/opensaml/xmlsec/signature/support/SignaturePrevalidator;)V
    at org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.authentication.OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider$SAML20AssertionValidators$3.<init>(OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider.java:732)
    at org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.authentication.OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider$SAML20AssertionValidators.<clinit>(OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider.java:731)
    at org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.authentication.OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider.lambda$createDefaultAssertionSignatureValidator$8(OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider.java:572)
    at org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.authentication.OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider.lambda$createAssertionValidator$11(OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider.java:654)
    at org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.authentication.OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider.process(OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider.java:495)
    at org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.authentication.OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider.java:448)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.servlet.filter.Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:222)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
```

But when I use the same code without setting the `authenticationManager`, then the SAML authentication works fine. (Any page that wants to use my custom `UserDetails` fails of course, because it's not being populated, but all the SAML authentication steps are working fine.):

```java
public class WigWebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests(authz -> authz.anyRequest().authenticated())
      .saml2Login();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turns out that I was using org.opensaml:opensaml-api 3.4.6, and you need to be using 4.x to use the class `OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider`. If you're using 3.x you need to use the deprecated class `OpenSamlAuthenticationProvider`. I wasn't able to upgrade the opensaml dependency because I'm using Java 8, so this is the code that works for me:

```java
public class WigWebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    // This class is deprecated, but you have to use it if you're using OpenSAML < 4.0
    OpenSamlAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new OpenSamlAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setAssertionValidator(OpenSamlAuthenticationProvider.createDefaultAssertionValidator());
    authenticationProvider.setResponseAuthenticationConverter(OpenSamlAuthenticationProvider.createDefaultResponseAuthenticationConverter());

    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests(authz -> authz.anyRequest().authenticated())
      .saml2Login(saml2 -> saml2.authenticationManager(new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider)));
  }
}
```

I finally found the answer when I discovered that that is what [Saml2LoginConfigurer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/e9f3da94fcf664499d9497926d5c53e2da859c2c/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/saml2/Saml2LoginConfigurer.java#L304) does internally.

Comment: Thank you for showing the `.saml2Login(saml2 -> saml2.authenticationManager...)` technique inside of the `configure(HttpSecurity..)` method. I had written a custom `AthenticationProvider` that internally uses `OpenSamlAuthenticationProvider` instance variable. I needed to use an instance variable because `OpenSamlAuthenticationProvider` is declared a final and so cannot be overridden. I tried to use the `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)` override method to inject the provider and it was not working. Putting in `.saml2Login(saml2->..` finally worked.